# How to get correct pdf size

Tags: c#

Hi I'm using some code as follows:

```
var f = new FileInfo(@"C:\sample.pdf");
var size = f.Length
```

When I inspect the file in explorer it shows a size of 214KB.

My code shows a size of 218.882KB.

Is this difference due to explorer not including metadata?

Can somebody tell me how through code I could get the 214KB figure?

Comment: `FileInfo.Length` returns file size in bytes. Are you dividing that by 1024 to get size in KB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
var fileLengthInKB = f.Length / 1024.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your C# code shows integer number.
Try calculating using those rules:

1 KB = 1024 B
1 MB = 1024 KB
etc.

Should match to what explorer shows.

Also, in the explorer compare 'Size' vs 'Size on Disk'.

Answer (score 0):

I already up-voted the right answer, but wanted to note that Windows is "incorrectly" reporting kibibytes (KiB), not kilobytes (KB).

While the KB was traditionally calculated as 2^10 bytes (1024) for decades, the IEC redefined the KB in SI terms (10^3 bytes) in 1999 and created the newer KiB unit of measure to take its place.